# array generated by python 2.X range() function

Tags: python, python-2.x

what happens to the array generated by python 2.X range() function at the end of loop  ?

Is the array deleted immediately or its present till the scope of respective function

Comment: If what you mean is when you do `for x in range(...):` then yes it is garbage collected after the loop since its reference count is 0.

Answer (score 1):

> Warning: For-loop variables “leaking” into the global namespace
>
> In contrast to some other programming languages, for-loops will use
>   the scope they exist in and leave their defined loop-variable
>   behind.

http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_python_scope_and_namespaces.html#warning-for-loop-variables-leaking-into-the-global-namespace

So, for example, `number` in : `for number in range(0,5)` will still be accessible after the loop (and will have the last value it was given.